# Server Data is not Coming: Angular2

Tags: java, rest, angular, typescript

I have created a simple app using REST in java which return string value successfully with REST client. Now I want to get string value using Http rest client in Angular2. I have created service for getting data from rest client in angular2 which saying successfully access rest but when I am printing data like {{serverData}} it's print nothing.

service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpSiftgridService {
private url:string = "http://localhost:8080/app-rest/rest  /get/getData";
constructor(private _http: Http) {}
getSiftgridData() {
    alert(this._http.get(this.url).map(res => res.json));
    alert("hh");
    return this._http.get(this.url).map(res => res.json);
}
private handleError(error : Response) {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || ' error');
}
```

}

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{ 
serverData: string;
constructor(private _httpService:HttpSiftgridService) {}
ngOnInit() {
    this._httpService.getSiftgridData()
        .subscribe(
          data => this.serverData = JSON.stringify(data),
          error => console.log("Error in getting Data"),
          () => console.log("Successfully")
    );
}
```

}

my rest app running on tomcat.

Comment: Can you manually fetch the data from the server with a web browser or curl? Is there an error on server side? Your URL definition contains two spaces. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
return this._http.get(this.url).map(res => res.json);
```

To:

```
return this._http.get(this.url).map(res => res.json());
```

Comment: thanx for reply, I changed but still coming as undefined

Comment: I'm going with Günter on this, the returned data from the server is not in the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not a real answer but that wouldn't work as comment:

If you change it to

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._httpService.getSiftgridData()
        .subscribe(
          data => {
            this.serverData = JSON.stringify(data);
            console.log(data);
          },
          error => console.log("Error in getting Data"),
          () => console.log("Successfully")
    );
}
```

is the data printed?
Is `Successfully` printed?

Comment: thanx for reply, Now it's printing **Error in getting Data**

Comment: Either remove the error line entirely to get a stack trace in the browser console or print `console.log(error)` instead of a const string to get the actual error information.

Comment: This is printing- SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Function.Json.parse

Comment: This means that what comes back isn't actually JSON

Comment: thnx, I remove json part and now it's comming as json data. But my requirement is getting only body data. How I can achieve this?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing more detail, but I'm pretty sure the response from the server is not in the correct format, otherwise `.json()` wouldn't cause issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122363/discussion-between-rish-and-gunter-zochbauer).